# Spark job runs longer locally after subsequent runs - tuning spark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job which runs in 5 mins on first initial runs and then takes several minutes ..more than 20-30 on subsequent runs. I'm reading a parquet file once and then creating dataframe and writing in .json format. I have not used cache(), persist() or unpersist() anywhere in the code.
This is local instance.
What could be the issue ?

**configuration parameters**

```
   val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .config("spark.serializer", 
  "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  .getOrCreate()

   //set new runtime options
   spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 14)
   spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "6g")
   spark.conf.set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
   spark.conf.set("spark.cores.max", "8")
   spark.conf.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", true)

   spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("somedirectorypath")
   spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is reading Parquet file and writing in JSON format?

Comment: You have to set `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.cores.max` BEFORE you create the Spark Session - setting this afterwards has no effect (you can check this on `localhost:4040`) ... but still... the relevant part of the code (reading parquet and writing json and whats happening in between) is not there

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing parquet in "append" mode, the first write is optimised as direct write to the location. Same for "overwrite" mode. The subsequent writes use the ParquetOutputCommitter which will first write to a temporary location and then copy the files to your target directory.